# Text-align justify but to the right?

Tags: html, css, layout

We want to make  text-align:justify, to take all the width of the column, but it should start from the right side.
Is there any way to make it with css or somehow?.

**EDIT:**

As suggested 
http://jsfiddle.net/dVbJr/33/

```
.text {
  text-align: justify;
  direction:rtl;
}
```

works, but it has punctuation issue.

**SOLVED**

```
    <span style="float:right">...</span>
```

This to be attached in the end has solved the punctuation issue.
Thanks for effort though to everyone! I shall accept the first answer then.

Comment: As in right-to-left (e.g. Arabic) text?

Comment: Check out this tutorial : http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/css-right-justify-pos-ie.php

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, not as an edit to your question.

Comment: Probably too late for that but I believe this was the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/3sf92oLg/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I believe you might want something like this:

```
direction:rtl;
text-align:justify;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aew75/

Comment: yeah that did it, but I just suddenly thought of it myself.
thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: @jason i m bit of agree with your answer we use this thing but now i have implemented u direction in my code text is going reverse back see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/dVbJr/33/

Comment: Shailender Arora you are absolutely right. it seems to have some problem with punctuation...

Comment: @ShailenderArora There is no problem with the punctuation or the implementation.  That's just what happens when the text needs to split on the right.  It will never look perfect; same thing happens with regular left to right justification.

Comment: how about if we make some float right wrapper? would it possibly work?

Comment: This is not proper solution because punctuation is changed. All dots, semicolons etc. are on wrong side.

Comment: Moves the punctuation.

Comment: Here is the point  solution for chrome and Mozilla users: https://davidwalsh.name/rtl-punctuation

Comment: This is not the right answer for LTR languages. Shobhit's comment below `text-align-last` is correct.

Answer (score 18):

```
text-align-last: right;
-moz-text-align-last: right;
```

If I understand the question correctly, the issue is really just how to right-align the last line of a justified block of text. The above does just that, using a property in [CSS 3 Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align-last) (with a vendor prefix version for better support), supported by modern browsers though not universally.

Though setting the writing direction to right-to-left causes this, among other things, it has several other, more fundamental effects. You may get away with it, if you don’t ever have inherently right-to-left characters in the text.

Comment: Doesn't work in Safari, so to me not a viable solution. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-align-last

Answer (score 5):

It can be solved by adding text-align-last:

```
div.a {
    text-align: justify;  /* For Edge */
    text-align-last: right;
}
```

Source: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-align-last.asp)

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is:

```css
p{
text-align: justify;
text-align-last: right;
}
```

```html
<p>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since. 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, 'just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'</p>
```

Only there is a problem with the last punctuation mark.

Answer (score -1):

check this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/6qrLF/)

for `right-to-left` you just need to set `direction:rtl`

Answer (score -4):

**CSS**

```
text-align: justify; 
text-align: right; // or text-align: left right;
```

Comment: no offense, but this is wrong: text-align value can only be left, right, center, justify or inherit

Answer (score -4):

Just try this.

```
text-align:right justify;
direction:rtl;
```

Comment: no offense, but this is wrong: text-align value can only be left, right, center, justify or inherit