# Right justifying text?

Tags: css, typography

I'm trying to come up with an example that experiments with different alignments as a demonstration. It's easy to left, center, right, justify, and center-left-justify text, as seen in my demonstration:

[image: a]

You can see this example [here](http://jsbin.com/avuzuf/1/edit) on JSBin. How can I get right-justified text without the punctuation getting messed up? (Notice the period to the left on the last line of the center-right-justified text.)

Comment: Why do you have `direction: rtl;`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684533/text-align-justify-but-to-the-right

Comment: @j08691, that's the only way to have the justified text's bottom line be right-aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work in IE (only):

```
text-align: justify;
text-align-last: right;
```

It doesn't look like there is a great cross-browser solution, but this might help:

[Justify the last line of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771304/justify-the-last-line-of-a-div)

Comment: Unfortunately, IE is the browser I'm least interested in targeting :(